# multiple search and replace in python

Tags: python, replace

I need to search in a parent folder all files that are config.xml 
and in those files replace one string in another. (from this-is to where-as)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What didn't work, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: why use Python for this? you could do this from a shell using find and sed.

Comment: It's a good ideea to document before-hand and try some ideas of your own and if you can't handle it ask a question, maybe with some code/ algorithm steps you tried. Not to be mean or anything but from your post it seems to me you didn't try anything and just expected someone else to solve your problem.

Comment: Acatually i did try.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
parent_folder_path = 'somepath/parent_folder'
for eachFile in os.listdir(parent_folder_path):
    if eachFile.endswith('.xml'):
       newfilePath = parent_folder_path+'/'+eachFile
       file = open(newfilePath, 'r')
       xml = file.read()
       file.close()
       xml = xml.replace('thing to replace', 'with content')
       file = open(newfilePath, 'w')
       file.write(str(xml))
       file.close()
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: i tried so far: import os
parent_folder_path = 'c:/test'
for eachFile in os.listdir(parent_folder_path):
    if eachFile.endswith('.xml'):
       newfilePath = parent_folder_path+'/'+eachFile
       file = open(newfilePath, 'r')
       xml = file.read()
       file.close()
       xml = xml.replace('Linux-ildev4', 'Linux09')
       file = open(newfilePath, 'w')
       file.write(str(xml))
       file.close()

Comment: so is it not replacing? or some other error? if it is not replacing then make sure that the text which you are replacing is there and `str.replace` is case sensitive also.

Comment: it doesn't replace anything. i did make sure that the text will be in the right case...

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) for recursively traveling through a folder and subfolders.

Then, you can read each line (`for line in myfile: ...`)  and do a replacement (`line = line.replace(old, new)`) and save the line back to a temporary file (`tmp.write(line)`), and finally copy the temp file over the original.

Comment: thanks. the example i was given didn't work :( it didn't do anything.