# Python: Scour a folder of files for a specific string, then list all the files containing it

Tags: python, file

I have a directory of ~100 plaintext files that I wish to search for a pre-defined string via a Python script. All file names of the files in said directory that contain this string will then be output into a CSV text file. How would I approach this best, and what classes would be useful for this?

Comment: Is this part of a larger program or do you just want to do a one-shot search? If you're only going to be doing this once, `grep` may work.

Comment: Following @icktoofay's comment:  That's for *nix systems.  On Windows you should try the [find command](http://www.windows-commandline.com/2011/04/windows-find-command-syntax-examples.html).

Comment: With which part of the problem did you get stuck when you tried writing this for yourself?

Comment: @GreenMatt: Cygwin could also be used.

Comment: @GreenMatt: This is indeed on Windows. Findstr worked beautifully for what I was trying to do, thankyou!

Comment: @icktoofay: Sure, Cygwin could be used, but if it's not already installed, that's overriding the point of a quick, one off solution.

Comment: @GreenMatt: I suppose, but it's useful for other things too. Might as well have it installed.

Comment: @GreenMatt Luckily there's an extremely useful port for windows too. Don't know what I'd do without it - [link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these links.

[Python Input Output](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

[Python CSV](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

[Common String Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html)

Answer (score 0):

please refer to these two answer of mine, may be this would help you.
[multiple search and replace in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022059/multiple-search-and-replace-in-python/7022133#7022133)
[regex search replace in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023460/regex-search-replace-in-batch/7024602#7024602)